# Ошибка при запуске скрипта

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, gtk

Скрипт легко запускается в PyCharm'е и его терминале. Однако, если попытаться запустить скрипт через cmd по команде

`C:\Users\Home-PC\PycharmProjects\box_vis\venv\bin\python.exe C:/Users/Home-PC/PycharmProjects/box_vis/visual.py` - выводится ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Home-PC\PycharmProjects\box_vis\visual.py", line 78, in <module>
    main = Main()
  File "C:\Users\Home-PC\PycharmProjects\box_vis\visual.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.builder.add_from_file(gladeFile)
gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-file-error-quark: Не удалось открыть файл «res/csgo.glade»: No such file or directory (4)
```

Хотя файл там присутствует и спокойно читается

сам код

```
import threading
import gi
import os

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib

sandboxie_path = "C:/Program Files/Sandboxie-Plus/Start.exe"  # Путь к Start.exe
Steam_path = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Steam/steam.exe"  # Путь к steam.exe
tn_host = "127.0.0.1"
port_list = ["2121", "2122", "2123", "2124", "2125", "2126"]
server_list = ["85.88.162.140:27031"]
pause = 15


class Main:

    def __init__(self):
        gladeFile = "res/csgo.glade"
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(gladeFile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)
        window = self.builder.get_object("main")
        window.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)
        window.show()

    def red_mark(self):
        for num in range(1, 7):
            self.builder.get_object(f"status_label_{num}").set_markup("<span background='#FA6DA4' "
                                                                      "foreground='#000000'>OFF</span>")

    def start_box(self, box_num, tn_port, server, sandbox_path, steam_path):
        os.popen(f'"{sandbox_path}" /box:{box_num} "{steam_path}" -applaunch 730 -netconport {tn_port} -novid '
                 f'-window -nosound +fps_max 30 -w 640 -h 480 +left connect {server}')
        self.builder.get_object(f"status_label_{box_num}").set_markup("<span background='#76EE98' "
                                                                      "foreground='#000000'>ON</span>")
        self.builder.get_object("progress_bar").set_fraction(box_num / 6)
        self.builder.get_object("log_lbl").set_markup(f'Box{box_num} запускается\n')

    # def empt(self, num):
    #     self.builder.get_object("progress_bar").set_fraction(num / 6)
    #     self.builder.get_object("log_lbl").set_markup(f'Box{num} не был выбран\n')
    #     print("d")

    def test(self):
        print('ff')

    def check(self, num):
        return self.builder.get_object(f"check_btn_{num}").get_active()

    def start_btn(self, widget):
        if not self.check(1) and not self.check(2) and not self.check(3) and not self.check(4) and not self.check(5) \
                and not self.check(6):
            pass

        else:
            counter1 = False
            counter2 = False
            for box in range(1, 7):
                if self.check(box) and not counter1:
                    counter1 = True
                    self.start_box(box, port_list[box - 1], server_list[0], sandboxie_path, Steam_path)

                elif self.check(box) and counter1:
                    threading.Timer(pause, self.start_box,
                                    (box, port_list[box - 1], server_list[0], sandboxie_path, Steam_path)).start()

                if not self.check(box) and not counter2:
                    counter2 = True
                    self.test()

                elif not self.check(box) and counter2:
                    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(3, self.test)
                    # threading.Timer(3, self.test).start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    main.red_mark()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: `C:\Users\Home-PC\PycharmProjects\box_vis\venv\bin\python.exe C:/Users/Home-PC/PycharmProjects/box_vis/visual.py` а в консоли какая папка была? Это папка называется рабочей директивой и относительные пути будут считаться от нее, т.е. нужно запускать от папки проекта, если в нем папка. Либо, получать абсолютный путь от текущей папки с скриптом, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/total_time_playlist_youtube_telegram_bot/blob/a2e69fb0466dbcf160492f32669a00579ed95a2e/config.py#L14

Comment: Спасибо, переместившись в папку проекта и используя относительные пути - команда заработала. Теперь вытекающее, как заставить pyinstaller избежать той же участи, ибо .exe по итогу выдаёт ту же ошибку